# PHP Redis session handler multi user

Tags: php, session, laravel, redis

Lets say we have a user, he logs in and browses the site like usual. Then we have lets say... the brother of this user and he wan'ts to login to the same account from a different ip or a different browser. Is it possible to check if redis has a current active session and deny access for this very reason to prevent multilogin for the same user?

Answer (score 0):

First, what does your question have to do with both `php` and `node.js` tags? In which one did you tried to implement your case?

Secondly, whatever the environment might be, what is stored into Redis depends on what you decide to store besides the session data. Usually session data stores a random `sessionid` and a `userid` associated to it. Nevertheless, in some cases you can chose to associate a session to a user than has not yet authenticated, therefore storing a session without any user associated to it.

Preventing concurrent user access from different IPs has more to do with the authentication mechanism, rather than session logic.

One approach for preventing concurrent logins from different IP address is to save a map of active users like `<userid, ip>`. Then after you check the credentials, you also check that map to see if the user is active from a different IP address. In that case you can deny the authentication.

This solution also implies some clean-up mechanism for users that do not safely logout, which is very similar to the session clean-up (time_to_live). To take advance of the existing implementation, you can add an IP address field to the session storage along with the userid at authentication using the same logic for authentication as previously described. The session will now look like `<sessionid, userid, ip>`. It's just a way to piggyback on the session storage and take advantage of it's clean-up process.

Comment: I'm sorry for the node.js tag, dunno why I added it. And since this will be done in PHP I added that. And I do believe it has to do with the session logic because I have to store the sessions on login in such a way its efficient to check if there's a session currently for a specific user on login, if there is one, we don't log him in, if there isn't one, we proceed.

Comment: I'm not familiar with any PHP example for session management, but based on the general concept, you do have a session for a user (unidentifiable) that has not yet authenticated. Think of the browser as the user. If you **only associate a session with a authenticated user** then you can prevent concurrent usage by checking if the user is enrolled in a session. If you only want to prevent concurrent usage from different addresses you need to add an IP field to the session.

Comment: I see, but instead of actually saving the ip, why not identify the user by cookie? because if his ip changes, he's screwed. And I've dealt with ip restrictions before in the past and its a pain to actually work as you want it to. Instead of actually using ip I was thinking that if you could save his phpsession id and userid in redis, next time someone tries to login using his credentials it will throw an error because there's a session already with the same userid.

Comment: You do identify the user by a cookie with the value of the `sessionid`. My answer was focused on weather you want to restrict access to 1 device or 1 location. Eg: **1 device:** User has a computer and a phone. He can only be logged in from 1 at a time. **1 location:** User can login from both computer and phone at home, but his credential cannot be used at his work computer if he's logged in at home. Ultimately, this decides if you need to add an `IP` field besides the [`sessionid`, `userid`] in Redis. *Continued ...*

Comment: Keep in mind that you only use the `IP` to restrict different locations, not for any session logic. You still use the `sid` cookie for authentication, only that you do a second check to see that he is requesting from the same origin (`IP`) he has authenticated. Again, my answer depends on what do you want to restrict: device or location.

Comment: Then you don't need to store any `IP`. You only query sessions by user.